# UNION of empty set with AVG function and any non-empty set

Tags: mysql, sql, database

this is my first question ever, so please be patient.. :)

We are two developers and both have the same MySql DB with same tables and values.

One is MySql version 5.5 and works ok (apparently) as I am told by the other developer.

On my machine with MySql 5.1.44 (a basic MAMP install) I have the following weird problem.

A very huge query (not mine) fails with error "Column 'xd' cannot be null".

Removing pieces I slimmedi it down to this:

```
select xd, avg(media) from questionario_punteggi where somefield = 1 union select 1,2
```

Note, there is **no record with somefield = 1** so the first select returns an empty set

We have a SELECT with AVG() function that returns an empty set UNION another SELECT that returns something (1,2 are just random values I put now as an example)

- If I remove the AVG() the query works.
- If I remove xd (and the 2 of 1,2 to the right) the query works.
- If I remove the UNION the query works.
- If I set some record with somefield = 1 the query works.
- On the other machine 5.5 the query works.

Otherwise the error is:

## 1048 - Column 'xd' cannot be null

Fields are:

```
`xd` char(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '001',
`media` decimal(7,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
`somefield` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
```

Gosh. Any help? Thanks.

**UPDATE**

**It has been reported to me as a BUG in MySql <= 5.1 that was fixed before MySql 5.5. I don't have the details but I trust the source**

Comment: Have you tried `UNION ALL`?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping `xd` in an aggregate? That query would be invalid in other RDBMSs as no `GROUP BY xd`. MySQL just gives you an arbitary row. I guess the problem is in this case there is no row to give you.

Comment: you'd need a `group by` in the simplified query anyways.

Comment: No, have not tried, unfortunately I am not the guy behind the query, so for any modification to the query I have to ask permission so I cannot experiment much. I can try locally. I will google UNION ALL

Comment: UNION ALL does not seem to fit. He has put UNION because he doesn't want duplicate values

Comment: Strangely [on SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a5a22/2) that gives an empty string rather than `NULL` even though there is no empty string in the data. I'd just alter the query to use `MAX(xd)` though I'm not sure why you are `UNION`-ing a `CHAR(3)` to an `INT` anyway?

Comment: As I said on the other developer (and much better SQL author) machine the query works perfectly. So there must be something between 5.1 and 5.5 version thatr changed. The int was just put as a test to display, the real query has same xd and media values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using the `SELECT IFNULL();`

```
SELECT IFNULL(xd,0), avg(media) 
FROM questionario_punteggi 
WHERE somefield = 1 
UNION
SELECT 1,2
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull

Comment: Added IFNULL(xd,0) and it stops the error, but I end up having a NULL result in avg(media). It returns 0 for xd and NULL for avg(media)

Comment: @FrancescoMM - `NULL` result in `avg(media)` is correct behaviour for an aggregate query with no `group by` over an empty set.

Comment: Thanks it woked, we had to use IFNULL(xd,'') instead as that was the expected value for an CHAR(3) but that is the idea

Answer (score 3):

I suggest reversing the order of the queries in the `UNION`.

This is because the first `SELECT` in a `UNION` determines the data type of the columns in the resultset; in your case, the first column of the `UNION` took the type of the `questionario_punteggi.xd` column: that is, `CHAR(3) NOT NULL`.

Since you are applying an aggregate function over the first part of the `UNION`, it results in a single row *even though* no records are matched by the filter criterion.  As documented under [`GROUP BY` (Aggregate) Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html):

> [`AVG()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg) returns `NULL` if there were no matching rows.

The value taken for the [*hidden*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-extensions.html) `xd` column would normally be an indeterminately chosen record from those that match the filter (which is why you probably don't want to do that anyway); however, since in this case no records match, the server instead returns `NULL` (which obviously cannot go into a column with the `NOT NULL` attribute).

By reversing the order of the `UNION`, the column will not have the `NOT NULL` attribute.  You may need to alias your columns appropriately:

```
SELECT 1 AS xd, 2 AS avg_media
UNION
SELECT xd, AVG(media) FROM questionario_punteggi WHERE somefield = 1
```

Using this to explain each of your observations in turn:

- > If I remove the AVG() the query works.

  Since aggregation is no longer performed, the first `SELECT` in the `UNION` yields an empty recordset and therefore no `NULL` record in the first column.
- > If I remove xd (and the 2 of 1,2 to the right) the query works.

  Since the hidden column is no longer selected, MySQL no longer returns `NULL` in its place.
- > If I remove the UNION the query works.

  This is the bug that was likely fixed between your version of MySQL and your colleague's: the `NOT NULL` attribute shouldn't really apply to the `UNION` result.
- > If I set some record with somefield = 1 the query works.

  The value selected for the hidden column is an indeterminate (but non-`NULL` value, due to the column's attributes) from the matching records.
- > On the other machine 5.5 the query works.

  This bug (I'm still searching for it) must have been fixed between your respective versions of MySQL.

Comment: @FrancescoMM: Then you could at least prefix the unions with something arbitrary like `SELECT '123' AS xd, 0 AS avg_media WHERE FALSE UNION ...`

Comment: We used IFNULL(xd,'') as on @jcho360 reply, but only on the first of the 23 unions, thanks to your suggestion